# Is there a way to restart FSI in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, f#, fsi

I'm learning F#, and keep accidentally writing infinitely recursive functions..

When I call these in F# Interactive (FSI) through Visual Studio (2010 or 2012), I can't find a way to get out of it other than to restart Visual Studio.  Is there any other - ideally faster - way out?

Comment: You want to cancel the current evaluation (right click on the FSI pane). No need to reset the whole of FSI, much less reboot VS!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Right click in the F# interactive window, and select `Reset Interactive Session`.

`Cancel Interactive Evaluation` should also work for you if you just want to cancel the current running function but to keep previous results.

Comment: Right click is the solution. Do you know how to let the shortcut `Ctrl-Break` (Cancel Interactive Evalution) work on a laptop? I tried `Fn+Ctrl+Pause`, (On my laptop, Break is on the Pause key color print.) It doesn't work.